# i7 8700k Intel graphics on Ubuntu

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics

I upgrade my system from 4th gen to i7 8700k with gigabyte z370n. But my graphics card (Intel UHD 630) can not load properly.I am running Ubuntu 16.04.

I have tried to add alpha_support to `/etc/default/grub` but it didn't work. And I have tried *intel-graphics-update-tool* which also didn't work.

How to fix it?

```
kurox@X-PC:~$ dmesg |grep -i i915
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-119-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=5e070fa0-319f-4d82-aabc-6c5cde6a47aa ro i915.alpha_support=1
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-119-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=5e070fa0-319f-4d82-aabc-6c5cde6a47aa ro i915.alpha_support=1
[   10.330260] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: failed to add i915_bpo component master (-19)
[   19.199696] Could not create tracefs 'i915_context_free' directory
[   19.199698] Could not create tracefs 'i915_context_create' directory
[   19.199699] Could not create tracefs 'i915_ppgtt_release' directory
[   19.199700] Could not create tracefs 'i915_ppgtt_create' directory
[   19.199703] Could not create tracefs 'i915_reg_rw' directory
[   19.199705] Could not create tracefs 'i915_flip_complete' directory
[   19.199706] Could not create tracefs 'i915_flip_request' directory
[   19.199707] Could not create tracefs 'i915_gem_request_wait_end' directory
[   19.199709] Could not create tracefs 'i915_gem_request_wait_begin' directory
[   19.199710] Could not create tracefs 'i915_gem_request_complete' directory
[   19.199712] Could not create tracefs 'i915_gem_request_retire' directory
[   19.199713] Could not create tracefs 'i915_gem_request_notify' directory
[   19.199714] Could not create tracefs 'i915_gem_request_add' directory
[   19.199715] Could not create tracefs 'i915_gem_ring_flush' directory
[   19.199716] Could not create tracefs 'i915_gem_ring_dispatch' directory
[   19.199718] Could not create tracefs 'i915_gem_ring_sync_to' directory
[   19.199719] Could not create tracefs 'i915_gem_evict_vm' directory
[   19.199720] Could not create tracefs 'i915_gem_evict_everything' directory
[   19.199721] Could not create tracefs 'i915_gem_evict' directory
[   19.199723] Could not create tracefs 'i915_gem_object_destroy' directory
[   19.199725] Could not create tracefs 'i915_gem_object_clflush' directory
[   19.199726] Could not create tracefs 'i915_gem_object_fault' directory
[   19.199727] Could not create tracefs 'i915_gem_object_pread' directory
[   19.199728] Could not create tracefs 'i915_gem_object_pwrite' directory
[   19.199730] Could not create tracefs 'i915_gem_object_change_domain' directory
[   19.199731] Could not create tracefs 'i915_page_table_entry_map' directory
[   19.199732] Could not create tracefs 'i915_page_directory_pointer_entry_alloc' directory
[   19.199734] Could not create tracefs 'i915_page_directory_entry_alloc' directory
[   19.199735] Could not create tracefs 'i915_page_table_entry_alloc' directory
[   19.199743] Could not create tracefs 'i915_va_alloc' directory
[   19.199744] Could not create tracefs 'i915_vma_unbind' directory
[   19.199745] Could not create tracefs 'i915_vma_bind' directory
[   19.199747] Could not create tracefs 'i915_gem_shrink' directory
[   19.199748] Could not create tracefs 'i915_gem_object_create' directory
[   19.199749] Could not create tracefs 'i915_pipe_update_end' directory
[   19.199751] Could not create tracefs 'i915_pipe_update_vblank_evaded' directory
[   19.199752] Could not create tracefs 'i915_pipe_update_start' directory
[   19.199755] i915: unknown parameter 'alpha_support' ignored
```

Comment: Firstly can you try 4.19 kernel?